# Java Spring Generic: Application context getBean -> unchecked assignment

Tags: java, spring, generics

Small question regarding Java Spring and Generic please.

I have a very straightforward interface as such:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {

    <S extends T> Mono<S> save(S entity);

}
```

With some classes implementing it:

```
@Repository("redis")
public class MyRedisRepository implements MyInterface<MyPojo> {

@Override
    public <S extends MyPojo> Mono<S> save(S entity) {
        return reactiveRedisOperations.opsForValue().set("someKey", entity.getValue()).map(__ -> entity);
    }
```

And in my code, I am trying to get the correct bean as such:

```
final MyInterface<MyPojo> myInterface = applicationContext.getBean("redis", MyInterface.class);
```

While I am able to get the correct bean, there is 100% of the time the warning on `applicationContext.getBean` `Unchecked assignment 'MyInterface' to 'MyInterface<MyPojo>'`

Is there a way I can get the bean as 'MyInterface' please?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a particular reason you wouldn’t inject it with `@Autowired` or similar? Spring should handle generics properly when you do that.

Comment: Good point @Didier, the reason why I am not using Autowired is because I have dozens of implementations of the interface, and I need to get the most appropriate one at runtime. Using Autowire will show limitation as in which one of the dozens to choose.

Comment: In that case I guess you actually have some `MyInterface<T>` at compile time, which makes it even more difficult to avoid the unchecked assignment. I suppose you might have some chance with [`getBeanProvider(ResolvableType)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBeanProvider(org.springframework.core.ResolvableType)), but it basically hides the unchecked assignment for you as it has no way to check that the `ResolvableType` matches the type you expect.